# Angular - Apply custom css to invalid FormControl, not FormGroup?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I use the Angular docs css classes for representing valid/invalid input:

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  {
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
    border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

But when I have nested `FormControls` (Inside `FormGroups`):

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    ies_Cabecera: this.fb.group({
        cab_DatosEstablecimiento: this.fb.group({
            cab_NIFEs: this.nifEs = this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
        })
    })
});
```

And the `cab_NIFEs` is not valid, I get this unexpected behaviour:

[image]

The css is also applied to the `FormGroup`.

This is the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="ies_Cabecera">
        <div formGroupName="cab_DatosEstablecimiento"  class="clear">
            <h3>Datos</h3>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label>NIF Establecimiento *</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="nifEs">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> How can I make the css be applied only to the invalid `FormControl`, not to
>   the `FormGroups`?

Comment: do you have a form tag for formgroup?

Comment: Edited with the code @tano

Comment: this error occurs because you have a div not a form tag. So you should change it to form, or change the css rule to .ng-invalid:not(div)

Comment: Sorry, I also have the form tag, I'm editing @tano

Comment: since you have nested formgroup you should also add the .ng-invalid:not(form):not(div) to the rules. The error should be indicated on the input field, so you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved applying the following css:

```
.form-control.ng-valid:not(form)  {
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.form-control.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
    border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

This forces the element to be a `FormControl` to be css applied.